# Reset Windows (8) Indexing Options

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-search

I changed my indexing options yesterday but it seems like I messed something up. I wanted to include a directory (where I store my music - about 5800 files) and I saw some directories there which I didn't needed to be indexed. So I did that, but now I have 2 problems:
  - when I search something from my start, it freezes a bit and searches pretty hard
  - it used to search through my Control Panel, and now it doesn't anymore. For example if I typed "Uninstall " it found "Uninstall a program" from control panel, but now it doesn't.

So I would like to reset the indexing options (because I don't really know exactly how they were set before). Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: [Just posted an answer on this exact same question](http://superuser.com/questions/707628/how-reset-indexing-locations-windows-8-1/1021979#1021979)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Control Panel, change the "View by" option to "Small icons" so you can see everything, then select "Indexing Options". You'll be able to rebuild and change index locations from there.