# How reset Indexing Locations (Windows 8.1 )?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have removed all my indexing locations from my Windows 8.1, and now I want to add them back.

How I can restore them automatically? When I try to add them manually I can't  find the folder with name `Start Menu`, and after I select the others ( `%appdata%` and `ie history`) I still can't find the application `Sound` when I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

I have tried to refresh my computer one month ago without resetting everything ... and after that I still can't find that application (Sound), and others, like  Disk Clean.

And another thing: When I perform a search my CPU usage goes to 100% (AMD 965 x4 3.40)

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 10 the indexing location rules are stored in the registry at the following location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\WorkingSetRules`
(in win 8 or lower it could be in a neighboring location, rest of the instruction would be same)

To reset the indexing location rules to their default, delete this key. (backup)

Deleting it however might not be straight forward, it'll give an "access denied" error, as there might be some services using it. Best way to edit this registry is through Windows Recovery Console environment which can be accessed via `Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced Startup > Restart now` then `Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Prompt`

When it restarts and the command prompt opens up, type in `regedit` to open the Registry Editor. 
However the registry loaded here by default, as well as the the `C:\` drive, **will not your actual one**, but that of the Recovery Console environment's. 
Your actual System Drive should be `E:\` or something. In the next steps you'll be able to browse the drives via Open File Dialog, figure out by your drive label, or files `E:\Users\<your account name>` which drive is yours. The registry on it should be in `E:\Windows\System32\config` directory, containing specific files (or "hives"), of which you want the `SOFTWARE` one.

So in the Registry Editor's left panel, select `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and then goto `File > Load Hive` and locate that `E:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE`. It will ask for a name under which to display the loaded hive, just type in `SOFTWARE_real` or something. 
Then delete the above mentioned registry key from its new hive `HKLM\SOFTWARE_real\...\Windows Search\...\WorkingSetRules`.

That's all, close it, exit, and restart normally. It will recreate the default registry values in the place of the deleted one and Indexing Options should now have those default Locations.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1′s universal search only shows files from folders it has indexed. One way to expand its reach is to add folders or whole drives to the index. However, the process of indexing your files and keeping that index up-to-date eats up system resources so, if you set Windows to index your entire system drive, you may slow the computer down. You’re better off choosing which folders you want indexed. Here’s how to add more folders or whole drives to your index.

1. Open the Windows Control Panel.
2. Click Indexing Options. If you don’t see an icon for Indexing Options select Large Icons from the View by menu.
3. Click Modify.
4. Select the folders you wish to index and Click Ok. The system will index any subfolders beneath them. If you select a whole drive, it will index all folders below the root level.
5. Click Close. The system will take a few minutes to add the new locations you added to its index.

P.S: Regarding the start menu locations:
If you do not see the Appdata folder you need to turn on the hidden files.

Per-user Startmenu: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
All user's Startmenu: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 (probably also before that) - you can delete this Registry Key to reset the Index Folder Locations to the Default value: (much easier than the upper suggestions with the Key that can not be deleted)

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search -> SetupCompletedSuccessfully - set this from 1 to 0

After, just stop and restart Windows Index Service. The Value will then again stay at 1 because it is resettet and completed.
In case you miss Outlook in the Locations, just reboot your computer once and start Outlook manually once, then open locations again - there it is.